# Pass a value from Main Activity to tab fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to pass a value from my `MainActivity` to my Tab `Fragments` so I can use that value accordingly. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
    //Value from Login Activity. The value I need to pass    
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");

    //Menu on my Drawer
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_request) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new RequestFragment()).commit();
    }

    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_requisitions) {
        FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new RequisitionsFragment()).commit();
    }
    return false;
}

});
```

The 3 Tabs belong to `RequisitionsFragment()`. That is where I need to pass the username value.

This is my `RequisitionsFragment()`:

```
    public class RequisitionsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
        return x;
    }


    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new PendingFragment();
                case 1 : return new ApprovedFragment();
                case 2 : return new CompletedFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return int_items;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Pending";
                case 1 :
                    return "Approved";
                case 2 :
                    return "Completed";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the part of `PendingFragment()` where I need to use the value:

```
public class PendingFragment extends Fragment {
.....
......    
private void sendRequest(){

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSON_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            showJSON(response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(PendingFragment.this.getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("username", username);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PendingFragment.this.getActivity());
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating `RequisitionsFragment` through a call to `new RequisitionsFragment()`. Instead of doing this, use the `newInstance()` method pattern. Something like this:

In your `RequisitionsFragment`, declare this method:

```
public static RequisitionsFragment newInstance(String username) {
    RequisitionsFragment fragment = new RequisitionsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("USERNAME", username);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And in your `MainActivity`, call this method thus:

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, RequestFragment.newInstance(username)).commit();
```

After this, when you need to access the arguments inside the fragment, call

`String username = getArguments().getString("USERNAME");`

That should do it. Let me know if this helps.

**EDIT**

Make these changes to your `RequisitionsFragment`:

```
public class RequisitionsFragment extends Fragment {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 3 ;
String username;

public RequisitionsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static RequisitionsFragment newInstance(String username) {
    RequisitionsFragment fragment = new RequisitionsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("USERNAME", username);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });
    username = getArguments().getString("USERNAME");
    return x;
}


class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return PendingFragment.newInstance(username);
            case 1 : return new ApprovedFragment();
            case 2 : return new CompletedFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return int_items;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Pending";
            case 1 :
                return "Approved";
            case 2 :
                return "Completed";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Then write a `newInstance()` method inside your `PendingFragment` as well:

```
public class PendingFragment extends Fragment {

String username;

public PendingFragment(){
    //Required empty constructor
}

public static PendingFragment newInstance(String username) {
    PendingFragment fragment = new PendingFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("USERNAME", username);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
.....//Initialize username inside onCreateView like this:
//username = getArguments().getString("USERNAME");
......    
private void sendRequest(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        showJSON(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(PendingFragment.this.getActivity(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PendingFragment.this.getActivity());
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Okay I will try. Thanks :)

Comment: Do let me know whether it works and if you have any doubts. And make sure the default constructor in your `RequisitionsFragment` is empty.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I tried it but my App closes when I choose Requisitions. I included a part of the PendingFragment() where I need to use the value "username".

Comment: Thanks for expanding your code, @AprilG. I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: It worked!!! Although I needed to remove the "()" in `case 0 : return PendingFragment.newInstance(username);` 
Sorry for the very late reply, it was already 2 AM here so I had to hit my bed :) But anyways, thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Glad I could help. And really sorry for leaving those parentheses there. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in PagerAdapter()

```
 Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
 bundle.putString(.....);
 new PendingFragment().setArgument(bundle);
```

Similarly you can call setArgument() function in Activity

Answer (score 0):

there is much better and powerful way to send data between classes .
[Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) support some interaction that you can not do with constructor class or interface. and for dynamic data communicating this third-party lib is perfect and easy use